# Wireless automatic disconnected

Tags: networking, wireless, kernel

**04-22-2015**

My internal wireless adapter become disabled (the wireless led indicator isn't lighted), when I mount my laptop on a laptop table from my desk. Restart Ubuntu is the only solution I know to make it work again.

The output of the script is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/wireless/04222015/wireless-info.txt), with no wired connection, and no external usb wireless adapter plugged in and with no driver modules  loaded.

The output of `lshw` is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/wireless/04222015/lshwoutput), with the external usb wireless adapter plugged in. Note that `wlan0` is my internal wireless adatper, while `wlan1` is my external wireless adapter.

What I have tried:

1. I uninstalled Network Manager and installed WICD, but the problem remains.
2. I followed http://www.hitxp.com/articles/software/ubuntu-fix-slow-wireless-internet-connection-speed-upgrading-11-04-natty-narwhal/, to add `/sbin/iwconfig wlan0 power off` to `/etc/pm/power.d/wireless`. That doesn't solve the problem (maybe make it less happen, but I am not sure.)
3. I followed https://askubuntu.com/a/541118/1471

   - add `options iwlmvm power_scheme=1` to `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlmvm.conf`
   - add `options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=Y led_mode=1 swcrypto=1 11n_disable=1` to `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`

   That doesn't solve the problem (maybe make it less happen, but I am not sure.)
4. I followed [Very slow, intermittent WiFi speeds with 14.04 and Intel PRO/Wireless 5100 AGN [Shiloh]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457986/very-slow-intermittent-wifi-speeds-with-14-04-and-intel-pro-wireless-5100-agn/464548?noredirect=1#comment854632_464548), to add `@reboot iwconfig wlan0 rate 54M` to `crontab` by `sudo crontab -e`. That doesn't solve the problem (maybe make it less happen, but I am not sure.)
5. 1-4 were tried before I upgraded kernel to Vivid's kernel 4.0 on Trusty. But after I made the kernel upgrade two days ago, the problem remains (I am not sure if that makes the problem less frequent.) The settings in 1-4 seem to apply to all installed kernel versions.
6. when my internal one doesn't work, I try to plug in my external usb wireless adapter. But the external one doesn't work either. 
   I remember with Trusty's kernel, most of the time, the external one worked when the internal one didn't, but  recently (before kernel upgrade) became not working either.

   Sometimes I wonder if it is more realistic and easier  to first make the external USB adapter work. It worked most of time until sometime before kernel upgrading and probably during I made those settings. Will the external one be easier to solve than the internal one?

**04-21-2015**

My wireless connection automatically drops once in a while.
Once that happens, I use WICD to reconnect to the wireless network, which shows that it puts down and up wireless interface. I wonder if there is some solution and/or reason?

The problem happens both before and after I recently installed 64bit generic kernel 4.0 from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.0-vivid/, on Trusty (i.e. Ubuntu 14.04), following http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/04/upgrade-to-linux-kernel-4-0-in-ubuntu/.

My output of running the script http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/wireless/kernel4.0/wireless-info.txt). I run the script after reconnection by WICD, not during disconnection.

Although now I can reconnect, I worry if [my previous wireless disable problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611786/wireless-interface-become-disabled) with Trusty's own kernel (i.e. before I install Vivid's kernel 4.0 ) still exists (and I just wait for that to happen, and I don't know a way to reconnect if that happens).

Thanks.

Comment: I see many parameters set for your driver, that seems like overkill and is probably hurting you connecting with wifi. Also it looks like you have a sleep script and the wifi is not waking up from it, did you do all these installs of ubuntu just by upgrading? and not a fresh install where you reformatted the drive?  Looks like you probably have configuration files from previous installs.

Comment: I made the settings before kernel upgrade, and the settings seem to apply to all installed kernel versions. (see my edit that adds what I have tried before)

Comment: sometimes I wonder if it is more realistic and easier to first make the external USB adapter work. It worked most of time until sometime before kernel upgrading and probably during I made those settings. Will the external one be easier to solve than the internal one?

Comment: @Tim Please give me a time we may meet in chat. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23105/room-for-chili555-and-tim

Comment: @Tim, I am going to be away most  of the day, I asked my good friend chili555 to help that is why he posted a chat request for you, it will be the best way for him to unravel the issues one at a time. He is the absolute best at wireless issues, I am a student of his.

Comment: Hi @chili555: Thanks. I am in the same time zone. We can chat most of time. How about this evening? By the way, shall I uninstall Vivid kernel 4.0 on Trusty because of [this system problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/612914/system-problem-and-should-i-uninstall-vivid-kernel-4-0-from-trusty)?

Comment: @Wild: Meanwhile, I am wondering if I should keep or uninstall Vivid kernel 4.0 on Trusty http://askubuntu.com/questions/612914/system-problem-and-should-i-uninstall-vivid-kernel-4-0-from-trusty