# Wifi keeps disconnecting on HP 2000-2c10DX

Tags: networking, wireless

My wifi keeps dropping connection constantly. I really want to use Ubuntu as a main OS, but this wifi problem is an issue. In the past, upgrading the kernel fixed it, but it isn't fixing the problem this time, unfortunately.

Here's some things I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Also tried purging bcmwl kernel source, turning off ipv6, upgrading the kernel, and disconnecting the wifi.

My CPU is a i3-3110m with HD4000.

[FULL specs of my laptop:](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03884428)

Only mentioned Intel drivers above as I know integrated drivers are very common, so there could've been an easy solution knowing the graphic drivers.

Comment: I am too facing the same issue.

Comment: Your hardware specification link does not provide hardware information for your WiFi card. Please provide full hardware details as explained [in this Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/q/235279/88802) (section **Identifying the exact hardware**). [edit] your question to provide those details. CPU/GPU specs aren't relevant, we need numeric vendor/product IDs of your WiFi chip to help you. Without this, it's just all guessing. Please also include the exact Ubuntu kernel version you are running (`uname -a`).

Comment: We need specific information about your Wifi chip. Please see http://askubuntu.com/questions/333424/how-can-i-check-the-information-of-currently-installed-wifi-drivers run the commands there and copy the output and [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/617542/edit) your original question with the new information.

Comment: Flagged as unclear because requested hardware information is not provided by OP.

Comment: have you checked your router settings that NOACK is not enabled? If NOACK is enabled, it can cause this type of behavior

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`. Do not reply via Add Comment.