# Have you done this?

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers

First some info
Laptop= HP Probook 450 G1 i5
Dual Boot Win7 Pro/Deepin
Ram = 8Gb
Wifi  = Intel 3160

Okay, so I installed Ubuntu Wednesday Night, but on my laptop and the new version of Ubuntu just did not like each other,the wifi was so slow.

I got the slow wifi fix with the Help of Serg, mikewhatever and Trinadh venea, (Again Thank You) but it was just not giving me what I wanted.

So Thursday Night I installed Deepin, and yes I know that it is based off of Ubuntu but it just was such a nicer looking OS.

Okay so now to what I did. I noticed that after the install the wifi SUCKED, and I mean worst then Ubuntu, but the Ethernet connection was great but the wifi not so much.

So I went back the my first post and went into the wifi setting and set IPv6 to Ignore  and the speed got better, but not good enough.

So I looked around the net and found someone that had downloaded the updated drive for their wifi adaptor and I followed the instruction and installed the updated firmwear.
BIG MISTAKE. I LOST WIFI and  Bluetooth. Thank God I made a backup of the firmware and just re-install them, but here is the weird thing the Wifi is now a lot faster.

**Questions:**
(1) Has anyone else stumbled on this.
(2) Is there a way to speed up the connection speed by tweaking the setting like SG TCP Optimizer for Windows.

Comment: Best way is to purchase a Linux compatible wireless =)

Comment: So you are running Deepin? That is off topic.

Comment: Organic Marble Sorry for being off topic, but it was a a very general question about installing and re-installing and NOT about Deepin. With that being said could you recommend a good Deepin Forum for a beginner???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu has better driver/hardware support than even some of the distros based off of Ubuntu.

For instance, when I made the switch to Linux, Debian & Mint did not have the wireless driver that I needed, and another (non-Ubuntu based distro) had a working wireless driver that flat out sucked.

Instead of using the current driver, you could remove it (back it up first) and use the Linux driver that Intel provides. http://www.intel.com/support/wireless/wlan/sb/CS-034398.htm

Comment: bodhi.zazaen I wanted to see if I could get it to work first before going that route..                                                                                                                                                                                                                    steaksauce That is what I did and it killed the wifi, but going back to the installed driver fixed it, which is what I do not understand. Wifi was giving me 5Mb down and 25Kb up, but after the stumble and re-install of the packaged driver it is now giving me 50Mb down and 7Mb up. Why would it do that?

Comment: @Scott. I'm not certain. To be clear: you tried the driver from Intel, stitched back, and got better speeds?

Comment: @steaksacue Yes,  I am kind of new to Linux but what I did should not make a difference.

Comment: Has anything changed with your wireless access point? Firmware, it being moved, you being closer to the access point? The Intel driver could have also modified your existing driver.

Comment: modified the driver is the only thing I can think of. Everything else is the same.

Comment: Well, I'm glad it's working regardless. If you truly want to know if it modified your driver or not, you can compare your driver to 1.) The downloaded Intel driver and 2.) An "un-adultered" version of the original driver (you can probably find this on your live USB or DVD if you have one). Let me know if you investigate it that far -- I would like to know :)

Comment: I am going to be looking at that to find out if there is a difference, as soon as I figure out how to do that.

Comment: This should help you out http://askubuntu.com/questions/333424/how-can-i-check-the-information-of-currently-installed-wifi-drivers

Comment: Thanks for the info. As soon as I get something I will post it.