# WiFI not available after installing TLP on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, tlp

This afternoon I installed TLP on my laptop running Ubuntu 14.04.

After the restart my WiFi suddenly stopped working
_ message: "Disconnected - you are now offline"
- I have a button on my keyboard that turns wifi on/off - now it just stays red and doesn't change (to blue) at all when pressed.
- In my network indicator now there no option even to turn wifi on/off and its the same in system settings

- `RFKILL LIST ALL` gives me:

```
hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no
```

And no wireless mentioned at all.

- Attempted fixes: (that did not work)

  1. Change the following in TLP's configuration:

```
WIFI_PWR_ON_BAT=1
WIFI_PWR_ON_AC=1
```

2. `sudo service network-manager restart`
3. I then uninstalled TLP (and purged) - still nothing
4. I then uninstalled other things I installed earlier in the day: Weather and calendar indicators, and preload.

   - NOTE: i noted in my software center there was 3 changes in the history that i did not recognise: Removal of : Python3 tz, Python dateutil and python3-dateutil (I do not know what these are signifying)

I do not know what wireless card I have or how to find that out.

Kindly assist me please

EDIT:

- Wireless card: EDIT: found this:  `RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller`
- Running the following didnt change anything

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms-linux-firmware
    sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Edit: Seems like my wireless driver has been uninstalled somehow? am I interpreting this correctly?

```
sudo lshw -c network
```

Output

```
description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
```

Nothing saying Wireless interface???

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with my WiFi card when I installed Ubuntu on my older laptop. The same issue with the WiFi being disabled occurred. I found that I had to install necessary WiFi drivers and I found [those](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2289959).

Works with my WiFi card listed below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rflwifi-new-dkms-linux-firmware
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Also, as far as looking for your wi-fi card you can find it by typing:

```
ifconfig
```

your wireless card should be under `wlan0` if not try:

```
sudo lshw -short
```

([reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333424/how-can-i-check-the-information-of-currently-installed-wifi-drivers))

This will display all current hardware including the wireless card which will be under the Class - Network category and have a description similar to something like this:

```
AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
```

Also, it seems like TLP will heavily configure your settings even overriding some of yours in order to save battery life or so I have read. You can try editing the configuration file by typing:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/tlp
```

and search for these settings: `WOL_DISABLE=Y` and `WIFI_PWR_ON_AC=1`
`WIFI_PWR_ON_BAT=5`

([reference](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html))

Comment: heres the reference: http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html

Comment: You are welcome. To be more specific, I would try changing the configuration settings in the TLP file first. Switch the WIFI_PWR_ON_BAT=5 to WIFI_PWR_ON_BAT=1  . It sets the wi-fi power saving mode which 5 means enabled and 1 means disabled. Obviously you want the power saving for your wifi card disabled.

Comment: Hi - the above fix didn't help. Also - I tried changing WIFI_PWR_ON_BAT=5 to 1 as noted in my post #1. Thanks for trying

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem,

I fixed my problem by

> Uninstalling TLP and Installing Wireless Drivers

Command: (to remove tlp) (sorry I have OCD)

```
sudo apt-get purge tlp
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean all
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Command: (to install 802.11 drivers) (I am on Kali rolling and using Wicd network manager)

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-brcm80211 firmware-b43-installer firmware-b43legacy-installer broadcom-sta-dkms
```

if you don't know the repository of Kali: ( Paste this in /etc/apt/souces.list and save )

```
deb http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

I also noticed, while installing tlp, the package arping was replaced by iputils-arping. Hence,

```
sudo apt-get install arping
```

**Restart Required**

Thats it!

(if this works for you, please upvote so I can get right to answer, comment, upvote, etc)