# Mobile broadband modem on acer aspire one not working

Tags: acer, modem, broadband

I've installed Ubuntu Mate 16.04 on an Acer 'aspire one' D 260. The inbuilt mobile broadband modem is not recognized any more after using the first time suspend mode.
It was working from the life stick I have installed Ubuntu, so in theory it should work but it's gone from network manager.

I just had put in another SIM card, Ubuntu is asking for the pin, and I can go online but after the first suspend it is gone again :(

Comment: If you shut down and restart does it work as expected?

Comment: surprising with the new SIM card it is connecting automatically after restart. But it did not so with the old card.

Comment: Pardon my confusion. I was under the impression that the problem occured coming out of suspend.

Comment: yes, it is coming out of suspend. now after suspend the problem is there again :)

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Comment: yes I have tried and it is working than (with a new SIM) but after suspend same problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43282/discussion-between-elder-geek-and-asklep).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this problem with numerous operating systems. the driver isn't re-initialized when coming out of suspend and has to manually be disabled and re-enabled to properly start. The easiest way I know of to accomplish this (regardless of operating system) is to reboot or shutdown and restart.

Another thing you could try would be to [stop and restart the networking service](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230698/how-to-restart-the-networking-)

**Edit:**

Another approach which may work for you is tag the driver for unload on suspend and reload on resume.

**1)** First we need to identify the driver in use. We can do this with the command `sudo lshw -C network | grep driver` (copy the driver name that comes after the driver= from the output of the command)

**2)** Next we need to write a configuration file with the command
sudo gedit /etc/pm/config.d/config

`sudo gedit /etc/pm/config.d/config`

Add a line that says SUSPEND_MODULES="driver name" where driver name is the value that you copied above. This does not always work but might in your case.

service

Additional Sources:

[How can I check the information of currently installed WiFi drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333424/how-can-i-check-the-information-of-currently-installed-wifi-drivers)

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2004690