# How can I access the BIOS Wireless SubMenu after pressing ENTER?

Tags: wireless

Computer: Lenovo IdeaPad.

I want to turn my Wireless Connection on, using the BIOS.
The Wireless LAN Device is enabled, as seen in the BIOS.
The option of Fn+F5 didn't work.

How can I access the BIOS Wireless SubMenu after pressing ENTER,
when there's no indication of such a Menu when pressing?

Help much appreciated.

Comment: How do you know it is disabled in BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve. Have you turned the wireless device on in BIOS.
There is a detailed guide on how to do this by Lenovo here https://support.lenovo.com/gb/en/documents/ht071417

If the device is correctly enabled then it is likely an issue with the driver. There are several suggestions on diagnosing the issue here: [How can I check the information of currently installed WiFi drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333424/how-can-i-check-the-information-of-currently-installed-wifi-drivers)