# Ubuntu 16.04 Wifi disconnect

Tags: wireless, 16.04

My Ubuntu laptop's wifi keeps disconnecting. It does it what seems to be randomly but frequently after periods of inactivity, though it does it when using the internet etc as well. I have to keep selecting the wifi network (I have the wifi network dialog box open permanently for this purpose). When this happens there will be period where it won't stay connected - it's like a click fest, where I select my network, it ticks it then it disconnects & unticks - repeat & rinse for about 30 seconds until it stays connected !!!!!! Really get on my nerves. 
Ran the network wireless info tool as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205)

Here is the results when connected [Connected Wifi Results](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23466036/)

When disconnected the same tool gives the follow error (no internet obv so doesn't work) -

```
https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info
Resolving github.com (github.com)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘github.com’
```

Any ideas ??? Presuming a driver issue.

Comment: What's your Wireless card? Don't tell me broadcom

Comment: Hi - sorry how do I find that info ? Is it on the wireless info file ?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/333424/how-can-i-check-the-information-of-currently-installed-wifi-drivers

Comment: Think it is a Broadcom - BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter

Comment: try following the answer, if it doesn't work notify me

Comment: The 1st command of the [linked answer](/a/425205/175814) downloads the diagnostics script and the 2nd marks it as executable. You don't need to repeat those two if you already did them one. That way you can also run the diagnostics without an internet connection (`./wireless-info`).

Answer (score 3):

We see that there are two wireless networks with the same name: SKY7D544. I am quite confident that most of the reason for the disconnects is that your wireless device is roaming between them, always searching for a better connection.

If these are routers over which you have administration priveleges, I suggest that you rename one or both; something like SKY7D544A and SKY7D544B. Then ask your wireless to connect to the strongest of the two and I'm confident it will stay and not disconnect.

If you are unable to rename them, I suggest you ask Network Manager to bind to the stronger of the two like this: [Ubuntu connect drops. Worked for a while then started dropping again](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425583/ubuntu-connect-drops-worked-for-a-while-then-started-dropping-again/425617#425617)

Comment: Thanks for the input. Where did you see two neworks called SKYD544 ? I only see one in my network list, but that could be my issue ! I had a look at the link you provide but can't find my MAC address as the command says scanning isn't supported in my interface.

Comment: Here is a snip from your wireless info: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23466476/ In the wireless info script, the MAC address is redacted. You will need to scan yourself to see it. `sudo iwlist wlp7s0 scan`

Comment: Right I have done a scan & copied the MAC address of what I think is the strongest signal & bound it to the BSSID. Let's see it works ! Thanks for all your help

Comment: Didn't work but I did work out what the other signal was on the same SSID - it's my Wifi booster upstairs !!! This problem existed before I had this booster so I know it's not that. It was a good shout tho'

Answer (score 1):

I have been having the same problem with Ubuntu 16.04 with Broadcom card.

The only thing which worked for me was installing [WICD](http://wicd.sourceforge.net/), a bit irritating that Network Manager can't cope but there you are.

I just installed it from the software centre but alternatively you could use:

```
sudo apt-get install wicd
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Cheers will give that a go !  The info above didn't work ! Still kept dying.

Comment: Tried installing WICD, which for a day seemed to work but last night the wifi disappeared ... totally !! I had no visibility of any network. Well it could see my network but it said it was out of range !!!!! The only was to get any connection is to restart the computer. Have uninstalled WICD but still getting this issue. Can't "system restore" in Ubuntu eh ? Don't know how to take it back to prior mucking around other than reinstall of unbuntu.  Oh shit.....

Comment: At my wits end with this. I've got to reboot every time the internet goes down (BTW I know the wifi is working as I can access my NAS drive but not the internet !) Do you think if I bought a USB Wifi adapter it would solve this ? How do you disable the internal wifi adapter ? Don't know where the device manager is in Ubuntu !!!