# Wifi very slow on HP laptop with Realtek controller RTL8188ee

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04

Also relevant, after a kernel upgrade, and reboot, there is **no** wifi.  Rebooting again and wi fi reappears.

I ran the command `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info` which created the file wireless-info.txt

Here is what I think is the relevant info in that file:

```
The kernel is linux 5.4.0-31-generic

 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)
        DeviceName: Realtek 802.11 b/g/n w/ *2 antennas
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8188EE mini-PCIe card [103c:197d]

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 08)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [103c:21de]
##### lsmod #############################

rtl8188ee             102400  0
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8188ee
rtlwifi                90112  2 rtl_pci,rtl8188ee
mac80211              843776  3 rtl_pci,rtl8188ee,rtlwifi
cfg80211              704512  2 rtlwifi,mac80211
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
hp_wmi                 16384  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
wmi                    32768  2 hp_wmi,wmi_bmof
##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp3s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'wlo1' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.0.234/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlo1
       valid_lft 5746sec preferred_lft 5746sec
    inet6 fe80::66ef:fcfd:a2e4:1687/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
##### iwconfig ##########################

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"saullubkin3"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'saullubkin3' [AC1]>
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-36 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:101   Missed beacon:0
##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlo1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter (RTL8188EE mini-PCIe card)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rtl8188ee
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.4.0-31-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlo1' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:02:00.0/net/wlo1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlo1
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     saullubkin3
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       6824f44f-18e0-4ff5-af8d-7c4ca83012f1
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     72 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
IFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.MESH:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.IBSS-RSN:               yes
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.234/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.0.1, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.0.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 7200
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        expiry = 1589915145
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        host_name = NullA-4
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.0.234
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        next_server = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       routers = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::66ef:fcfd:a2e4:1687/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 600
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/2
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   6824f44f-18e0-4ff5-af8d-7c4ca83012f1 | saullubkin3

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         p2p-dev-wlo1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi-p2p
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifiP2P
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         --
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        --
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         (unknown)
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 --
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         (unknown)
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         42 (The supplicant is now available)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /virtual/device/placeholder/0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 --
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp3s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:03:00.0/net/enp3s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --
SSID         BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  IN-USE
Saulubkin3   <MAC 'Saulubkin3' [AC2]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  195 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WPA2       no
saullubkin3  <MAC 'saullubkin3' [AC1]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  260 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2  yes     *
--           <MAC '' [AC3]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  65 Mbit/s   100     ▂▄▆█  WPA2       no

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

cat: /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state: Permission denied

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3
SSID         BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  IN-USE
Saulubkin3   <MAC 'Saulubkin3' [AC2]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  195 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WPA2       no
saullubkin3  <MAC 'saullubkin3' [AC1]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  260 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2  yes     *
--           <MAC '' [AC3]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  65 Mbit/s   100     ▂▄▆█  WPA2       no

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

cat: /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state: Permission denied

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3
SSID         BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  IN-USE
Saulubkin3   <MAC 'Saulubkin3' [AC2]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  195 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WPA2       no
saullubkin3  <MAC 'saullubkin3' [AC1]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  260 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2  yes     *
--           <MAC '' [AC3]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  65 Mbit/s   100     ▂▄▆█  WPA2       no

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

cat: /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state: Permission denied

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3
lo1      13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHzlo1      Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'saullubkin3' [AC1]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-38 dBm
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"saullubkin3"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000684ba831e
                    Extra: Last beacon: 68ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'Saulubkin3' [AC2]>
 Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-34 dBm
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Saulubkin3"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000681f792f7
                    Extra: Last beacon: 68ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC '' [AC3]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-31 dBm
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:""
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
 Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000683b02052
                    Extra: Last beacon: 536ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[rtl8188ee]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8188ee/rtl8188ee.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8188efw.bin
description:    Realtek 8188E 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         zhiyuan_yang    <zhiyuan_yang@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     23DD123075FCCEAB135BFA9
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl_pci,mac80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rtl8188ee
vermagic:       5.4.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        06:5F:5E:F6:6C:B6:97:58:DF:7B:9A:BB:27:14:9D:3D:7B:DB:36:6B
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           aspm:Set to 1 to enable ASPM (default 1)
 (int)
parm:           debug_level:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)
parm:           debug_mask:Set debug mask (default 0) (ullong)
parm:           disable_watchdog:Set to 1 to disable the watchdog (default 0)
 (bool)

[rtl_pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko
description:    PCI basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming      <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     359AF533CEBD24E6328F94E
depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rtl_pci
vermagic:       5.4.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        06:5F:5E:F6:6C:B6:97:58:DF:7B:9A:BB:27:14:9D:3D:7B:DB:36:6B
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
[rtlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming      <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     CA222FB0D904D3167D83D45
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rtlwifi
vermagic:       5.4.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        06:5F:5E:F6:6C:B6:97:58:DF:7B:9A:BB:27:14:9D:3D:7B:DB:36:6B
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-31-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     B031A4C3E5E44DEFDCE0585
depends:        cfg80211,libarc4
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       5.4.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        06:5F:5E:F6:6C:B6:97:58:DF:7B:9A:BB:27:14:9D:3D:7B:DB:36:6B
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-31-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     C806D0B3412B28507AE57E5
depends:
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       5.4.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[rtl8188ee]
aspm: 1
debug_level: 0
debug_mask: 0
disable_watchdog: N
fwlps: N
ips: Y
msi: Y
swenc: N
swlps: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500
[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode
[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8188ee.conf]
options rtl8188ee ant_sel=1

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   54.464015] wlo1: authenticate with <MAC 'saullubkin3' [AC1]>
[   54.474180] wlo1: send auth to <MAC 'saullubkin3' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   54.476849] wlo1: authenticated
[   54.479697] wlo1: associate with <MAC 'saullubkin3' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   54.484715] wlo1: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'saullubkin3' [AC1]> (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=4)
[   54.484715] wlo1: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'saullubkin3' [AC1]> (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=4)
[   54.485012] wlo1: associated
[   54.798471] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready
[ 1077.620889] wlo1: deauthenticating from <MAC 'saullubkin3' [AC1]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 1078.682596] rtlwifi: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[ 1081.918328] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Down
[ 1084.049624] wlo1: authenticate with <MAC 'saullubkin3' [AC1]>
[ 1084.059744] wlo1: send auth to <MAC 'saullubkin3' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 1084.062962] wlo1: authenticated
[ 1084.064063] wlo1: associate with <MAC 'saullubkin3' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 1084.069155] wlo1: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'saullubkin3' [AC1]> (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=6)
[ 1084.069451] wlo1: associated
[ 1084.097559] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############



          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
```

Comment: The Operating system is Ubuntu 20.04 desktop.

Comment: Do you know if your [drivers](https://askubuntu.com/a/333430/212930) are correct?

Comment: The driver being used for wi fi I believe is rtl8188ee, which I believe is the correct one.