# No WiFi on Kubuntu even after disabling secure boot?

Tags: networking, drivers, nvidia, kubuntu

I recently installed Kubuntu v20.04.1. After some issues with a second screen not working over HDMI, I switched from the default xorg nouveau video driver to the proprietary Nvidia one.

Somewhere during this process, I was asked to enable secure boot which I did. Upon reboot, I was presented with the MOK menu and enrolled the key.

When the OS started again, I could no longer access my Wifi network. Digging around, I disabled secure boot both in my BIOS and in Kubuntu. Running `mokutil --sb-state` confirms this as it shows `SecureBoot disabled`.

However, I still cannot access Wifi. No Wifi networks show in the network part of the system tray. Using [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333424/how-can-i-check-the-information-of-currently-installed-wifi-drivers) answer, I tried a few other things.

Running `sudo lshw -C network` produces the following regarding my Wifi adapter:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
  description: Network controller
  product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
  vendor: Intel Corporation
  physical id: 0
  bus info: pci@0000:52:00.0
  version: 1a
  width: 64 bits
  clock: 33MHz
  capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
  configuration: latency=0
  resources: memory:ceb00000-ceb03fff
```

Both contrast, my Ethernet interface has a `driver=` field in its `configuration` line, and doesn't say `UNCLAIMED` at the top.

Running `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280` gives:

```
52:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: ntel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:0080]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

This doesn't mention that any kernel drivers are in use. I can run `find /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless -name '*.ko'` and see that a load are installed.

This leads me to think that the driver has almost come "unplugged" and it's a case of linking it back up but I don't know enough about Linux to confirm this.

Unfortunately, my laptop doesn't have an ethernet port so am unable to update anything to see if this would fix the problem. I've tried moving back to the nouveau graphic driver and rebooting but nothing changed.

How can I go about fixing this error?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of two terminal commands. First: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` and second: `dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to fix it. I have Kubuntu installed with Windows as a dual boot.

I booted into Windows and found that Wifi was turned off. I turned it back on again, reconnected to my network, booted back into Kubuntu and suddenly it was working again.

Weird fix, but maybe this will save someone else three hours of woe.

Comment: I can only imagine this was resolved due to Linux getting a reboot.